# How to trouble-shoot issue where Expo push notifications not delivered for some devices

Tags: notifications, push, expo

Our app uses Expo push notification to deliver push messages. It works just fine for most clients, but I am trying to debug one client where he is not receiving the push messages. Here is what I am seeing:

- Using Expo push notification tool as well as my own client code, I
  can send messages to his Expo push token. Expo server responds with
  ok status. I checked the status given the receipt id and the status
  also says ok.
- But the client never receives the messages. I ensure
  that the app is not already opened on his iOS device and that
  notification is enabled for the app.

My question is: how do I debug this further? I understand that Apple server might decide to send or not to send messages based on various factors. How do I find out what Apple server did with the messages?

I have googled quite a bit but I couldn’t find much info on how to proceed. I hope that someone has experienced the same, and can help with some leads.

Thanks for your help,

Huey